# No suitable method found? Please assist me in completing this?

Tags: java, arrays

I was wondering how can I use the `remAll` method on the very bottom of my code.
**Whenever I try to use `out.println(list.remAll());`**, it gives me an **error** saying

**"No suitable method found for remAll"?**

How can I fix this?

**I have also tried using `out.println(remAll(list));`**

I'm a beginner when it comes to Java and I am just learning, so pardon me if this is much simpler than it looks. P.S. Sorry if the format is wrong or something. It's my first post here.

```
        import java.util.*;
        import static java.lang.System.*;
        public class StringArrayListLoader 
        { 
            public static void main(String args[]) 
            { 
                Scanner kb = new Scanner(in); 
                out.print("Size of list? "); 
                int s = kb.nextInt(); 
                ArrayList<String>list = new ArrayList<String>(); 
                out.println("Enter the Strings:  "); 
                for(int x = 0; x < s; x++) 
                { 
                    out.print("String " + x + " :: "); 
                    list.add( kb.next()); 
               }
                out.println("\nThe ArrayList you entered is ..."); 
                out.println(list); 
                out.println(beginWithx(list) + " of the Strings begin with an \'x\'");
                out.println(firstLast(list) + " of the Strings begin and end witletter.");
                out.println("First String = Last String? " + firstLast2(list));
                out.println(*******); // what am i supposed to put here?
    } 


    public static int beginWithx(ArrayList<String>ar)
    {
        int count = 0;
        for(int i = 0; i<ar.size(); i++)
            if("x".equals(ar.get(i).substring(0,1)))
                count++;
        return count;
    }
        
    public static int firstLast(ArrayList<String>ar)
    {
        int counting = 0;

        for(int i = 0; i<ar.size(); i++)
            if(ar.get(i).substring(0,1).equals(ar.get(i).substring(ar.get(i).length()-2, ar.get(i).length()-1)))
                counting++;
        return counting;
    }

    public static boolean firstLast2(ArrayList<String>ar)
    {
        int counting = 0;
        if(ar.get(0).equals(ar.get(ar.size()-1)))
            return true;
        return false;
    }

    public static void remAll(ArrayList<String>list, String s)
    {
        int i=0;
        while(i<list.size())
        {
            if(list.get(i).equals(s))
            {
                list.remove(i);
            }
            else
            {
                i++;
            }
        }
        out.println(list);
    }
}
```

Comment: `remAll` needs two parameters.  You're trying to call it with zero or one.  That's the explanation for the error message.  Also, `remAll` is a `void` method, so trying to use the result as a `out.println`  parameter doesn't work, since there is no result.  In fact, `remAll` does its own output, so you don't need to call another `out.println`.

Comment: No I have not learned that. I am currently taking a computer science class and this is our assignment due on Friday. Our professor is not offering assistance and he told us to ask our peers. Unfortunately, the people I have asked are not sure as well. P.S. - Thank you for the reply! I got it working.

Answer (score 0):

Your `remAll` method takes two parameters, an `ArrayList<String>` and a `String`.  You must pass two parameters to call the method properly, such as

```
remAll(list, someOtherStringHere);  // remAll has its own "out.println" calls
```

Answer (score 0):

The method signature is

```
public static void remAll(ArrayList<String>list, String s)
```

So, you need to call it like:

```
remAll(list, "some string");
```

By inspection of the code, it will then remove all instances of "some string" from the list.

Comment: Thank you for replying! I have tried to fix it and it now says 'void' type not allowed here."
EDIT: Oops, sorry I should have read ajb's comment

Comment: @user3381441 ummm, that doesn't help us, because we don't know what code you're getting the error on or what your fixes were.

Comment: My apologies. I made it an out.println(remAll(list, "blah"); and then afterwards, I saw your comment. I just removed the out.println and got it working.